# Running Barrier at startup

Tags: boot

I'm having trouble running barrier at startup.
I was able to make it run after logging in, the thing is I want to use my main mouse and keyboard from another pc on this one. meaning I either need to keep it always on, or connect a mouse and keyboard to log in.
any idea on how to bypass it to make it run on boot?
thanks!

Comment: You can find lots of people asking about it and talking about it in the past on the project issues list, for example: https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/issues?q=is%3Aissue+login but I could not find a working solution or any documentation. One horrible workaround (which may be good enough for some if security is not an issue) is to set your ubuntu user to auto-login, then have a startup script to lock the screen `gnome-screensaver-command -l` and start barrier etc.